# Assigning a string variable in a dos FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

I have this file structure where each subdirectory contains particular file types, lets say pdfs.

ParentDIR
-->SUBDIR1
-->SUBDIR2

I am trying to run a batch file from the parent to recursively return paths so I can parse them and perform some action

```
@echo off  
for /R %%v in (*.pdf) do (  
set pathname=%%~pv  
echo %pathname%  
)
```

I would expect the output of the path variable here to read

\PARENTDIR\SUBDIR1
\PARENTDIR\SUBDIR2

but it reads

\PARENTDIR\SUBDIR2
\PARENTDIR\SUBDIR2

If I echo the value of %%~pv without assigning it to a variable, it is correct.

How can I get the value of this variable to be assigned correctly at each iteration through the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off >Nul 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /R %%v in (*.pdf) do (  
set pathname=%%~pv >Nul
echo !pathname!
)
endlocal
```

Here mind `EnableDelayedExpansion` keyword of [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) command = Expand variables at execution time rather than at parse time, if used `!pathname!` syntax instead of `%pathname%` one.